# ubuntu server temporarily stop all network traffic

Tags: ubuntu, bash, terminal, openvpn

I have an ubuntu machine connected to a openvpn server with inbound and outbound connections. In terminal, what is the best/cleanest/safest/least disruptive way to quickly stop/block all network traffic and then start/allow all network traffic again?

Additional info: Ultimately this will be done regularly and via a script

Answer (score 3):

You can always disable a network interface with `ip`.

To disable eth0 for example:

`ip link set eth0 down`

To enable it again:

`ip link set eth0 up`

Comment: Great, In my case for the above to work it will be: stop vpn, disable network interface, enable network interface, start vpn. This takes about a second and a half. I may explore achieving the same effect with firewall rules as that may be an even shorter break.

Comment: @TBAR If you need to do this more often, there is always the possibility of creating an `alias` or script. You might want to edit your question with your specific usecase so that others can make better recommendations.

Comment: note to self: don't run this when you're connected via SSH or you'll have to manually access the on-premise terminal.

Comment: @ChristianNoel Simplest thing to prevent that (if you want to restart your networking) would be to run both commands sequentially by separating them with `;` or `&&`.

Comment: @mashuptwice interesting! that's true, i should have added a sleep 30 seconds to automatically restart the network so in-case i get disconnected, there's a revive. thanks for the insight!